# Powerpoint slideshow escape vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

is do have a powerpoint presentation that will be opened in slideshow mode directly from Excel.
i've managed from powerpoint VBA to close the slideshow without asking to save the file. 
unfortunatelly if the user press "ESC" key duing the presentation the slideshow get closed and the pop-uop asking to save the file is showed.
i don't want to disable the escape key in the powerpoint. just need to know where, if existing, to place eventual VBA code to place my code

```
With Application.Presentations
    .Saved = True
    .Close
End With
```

or any other way to prevent PPT to get saved (or asked to)

thanks
P.S. i'm using PPT2016

Comment: Untested, but you may be able to use [`Application.DisplayAlerts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.displayalerts). Just make sure that the application in question is the PPT application.

Comment: PowerPoint has a DisplayAlerts property, but it's never done anything useful, at least not the way it does in Excel.  Luca, set the activepresentation's .Saved property to true whenever your code makes any changes to the presentation.  That should do it.

Comment: you can add you code in OnSlideShowTerminate() event.